# MySQL: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1054

I'm doing some changes on a WordPress database. I need to replace the URLs in the GUID field on the wp-posts table with the URLs coming from another table called ebdurls. The description of the tables is as follows:

wp_posts: the field type for the two fields I need are:

***ID -> bigint(20) unsigned***

***guid -> varchar(255)***

And the table where I have the data I need to export to wp_posts is this:

ebdurls:

***title -> varchar(255)***

***url   -> varchar(255)***

***ebdid -> bigint(20) unsigned***

Everything seems correct, but when I apply the next query it gives me an error that I really can't get. I've tried quoting fields, tables, etc... everywhere, but no luck.

**mysql> update wp_posts set wp_posts.guid=ebdurls.url where wp_posts.id=ebdurls.ebdid;**

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ebdurls.ebdid' in 'where clause'

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what ebdurls is, add a from statement to your query:

```
UPDATE 
    wp_posts, ebdurls
SET 
    wp_posts.guid = ebdurls.url 
WHERE 
    wp_posts.id=ebdurls.ebdid;
```

**edit:**
Bill was right, have fixed the format now. Oops.

Comment: That's Microsoft SQL Server syntax for multi-table UPDATE.  MySQL orders the clauses differently.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

`ebdurls.*` has no value. That is what is causing your error. The database has no idea what you are trying to do.

You probably need to use a subquery or add this logic into your application.

Or something like:

`UPDATE wp_posts, ebdurls ...`